# Django-python coding explanation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

What is static method and how can we explain the below code ?

```
  @staticmethod
    def get_model(**kwargs):
        try:
            return Model.objects.get(**kwargs)
        except Model.DoesNotExist:
            return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short and maybe oversimplified: `staticmethod` doesn't require object of a class to run. This also means that you don't need `self` argument.

About the code:
This method is attempting to return single (.get()) instance of a Model that match with parameters specified in kwargs.

example:

```
kwargs = {"id":5, "is_alive": True}

Model.objects.get(**kwargs)

#is the same as

Model.objects.get(id=5, is_alive=True)
```

This can raise Model.DoesNotExists error if there is no instances of Model matching with paramaters so try/except is used.

If Model.DoesNotExists error is raised then method return None.

Answer (score 1):

A `staticmethod` is a function not bound to an object, but is encapsulated within it ( typically to reduce outer namespace clutter, or eliminate any need to import it). It doesn't have the first `self` argument that a normal object method does.